# How to add a form field which accepts the date of birth of a person?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, devise

I'm creating a form in which there will be a select box for day, month and year to store the date of birth of a person? I'm using devise and going to customize it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery UI Datepicker:
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

There are plenty of other Datepickers around, just google it and find what is best for your stack. If you are using Twitter Bootstrap, here is something:

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [date_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) helper. Or you could use [jquery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)